# Call requests in order react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, request

I'm currently working on a class project to develop a chat app using React Native (Expo project). I've encountered an issue where, in a component, I need to make two requests: the first one is triggered when the component is mounted, and the second one is initiated when the user clicks a button.

My proposed solution involves using a state variable to determine whether the first request has been completed successfully before executing the second one.

Now I have:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //call first request to get data for value ...-> data
    setValue(data);

  }, [])

  //CASE1: call in another useEffect 
  useEffect(() => {
    //call second request using the data of value
    if(value != null) {
      //call
    }

  }, [dependency , value])

  //CASE2 call in a handle function when user clicks button

  const onSend = (message ) => {
    /*
    if(value != null ) {
      call request using that value to create a new "store" document
    }
    else {
      call request to store new message to that store
    }
    */
  }
```

Case 1: In this scenario, I've included the 'value' state as a dependency in the second `useEffect`, ensuring that the 'request' is only invoked when the 'value' is updated.

Case 2: I haven't found a solution for this case yet, and I'm wondering how to handle situations where a user clicks a button too quickly, potentially sending two messages too rapidly.

Can you give some comment, idea and solution for both cases?

Comment: Your first part is fine, but you should consider using error handling to ensure the second request runs only after the first one succeeds. As for your concern regarding rapid clicks, you should consider using a loading state to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @JKhan Thank you for your answer, but I'm concerned that setting a loading state to prevent users from chatting continuously may affect their experience. Does this depend on my request or my back end (BE)?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a promise, in your onLoad useEffect you call an async function that will wait for the data response. Then once its done it will call resolve or reject on anything that was waiting for it.

There might not be any resolves or rejects if the user didn't press the button fast enough but if they do then there will be a resolve waiting in the array to complete the onPress Action.

The resolve and reject is added to the arrays whenever the button is pressed and there is no value in the state variable, assuming that if we don't have a value in state its not done loading yet. Then we wait for that promise to resolve or reject before continuing on to load someOtherData.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, View } from 'react-native';

let resolves: ((result: any) => void)[] = [];
let rejects: (() => void)[] = [];


export const someComponent = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState<any>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadSomeData();
    }, []);

    const loadSomeData = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await fetch('some url');
            resolves.forEach(resolve => resolve(result));
            setState(result);
            resolves = [];
            rejects = [];
        } catch (e) {
            rejects.forEach(reject => reject());
            rejects = [];
        }
    }

    const onPress = async () => {
        if (isLoading) {
            return;
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            if (!state) {
                await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolves.push(resolve);
                    rejects.push(reject);
                });
    
            }
    
            const someOtherData = await fetch('some url');
        } catch (e) {
            // handle error if the Promise is rejected from the rejects or from the someOtherData call.
            
        }


        setIsLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Pressable onPress={onPress} />   
        </View>
    )

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm concerned that  the onPress handler contains a message in its argument, and the user sends two messages too quickly,
 the second message might be missed because the isLoading state is false

Comment: Honestly I just threw the loader in there because you said you wanted to stop accidentally submitting twice. You can remove if if you like and this will still accomplish your question of how to make the multiple requests in order. Although the loader could do some other UI stuff as well like hide the button and show the loader until the send is completed or just disable the button until it's done loading. I feel like there are a lot of different opinions for this and is really a different question.

Comment: I apologize for my communication causing you to misunderstand, but my exact intention is not to delay the user's chatting experience. They can chat as fast as they want, and the UI will update instantly. However, the calling requests will be processed in order to ensure that no messages are missed

Comment: To provide more details, when a user searches and then clicks on another user:

I want to initiate the first request to check whether a private chat has been created between them and retrieve its value.
When the first user sends a message:
If there is no private chat, initiate a request to create a new one and store the first message.
If a private chat already exists, initiate a request to store the new message in the existing private chat.
All subsequent messages will be stored in the newly created or existing private chat

Comment: So I think my answer above should help you with getting the private chat setup before sending the first message. The other information with regards to instant send. I have done this before but what I did was faked it with the UI so I would send off the message to the backend clear the text input and create a local message component that was waiting for the real response from the backend. This is going to add a lot more complexity because you will need to make sure to handle errors after the fact. I did this by attaching the call to the message component so it could mark the message as failed.

Comment: Oh, the problem is more complicated than I think . Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think it might be helpful to ask another question being more specific about your needs, because I feel like my answer is answering the question you asked above at least in the way that you wrote it or in the way I am reading it. Best of luck solving your problems.